# .htaccess rule issue

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I am currently writing rules for my pages, with .htaccess.

I have a forum, the original URL of this is: **?i=f**

This will then be rewritten to:

```
RewriteRule ^forum /?i=f [L]
```

This works. Although here comes my problem. When I wish to go deeper into the pages, to the categories of the forum, the actual URL is: **?i=f&p=t&cid=ID**

What I try to do is this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/cat/([^/]*)$ /?i=f&p=t&cid=$1 [L]
```

Although that does not work, since the /forum is already defined. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `RewriteRule ^forum /?i=f [L]`
and add Just this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^forum(?:/cat/([^/]*))?$ /?i=f&p=t&cid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @user169691 That does not explain anything! You have to give details!